# Cursor stuck at loading position on iPhone iOS safari, iOS google chrome, iOS Mozilla

Tags: aframe

I recently started using A-frame to develop VR experiences. My first project is a simple virtual tour of a city. The frame work seems to be working fine on desktop browsers and on iOS except for one condition. When I enter the VR mode on iOS, the cursor get stuck at the load position.

Some specifics of my project is that I've stored my a-entity objects in JSON and render them through elements.js

You can see my project at https://thearchmedia.com/3d-tours/tampere-tour/vr/

I understand that support for iOS is said to be quirky on aframe.io, but I'm curious if there is a solution for this problem. I'm just started experimenting with a-frame so if you see any issues with the code feel free to let me know.

Here is my code! Any help would be appreciated.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.3/aframe.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-template-component@3.x.x/dist/aframe-template-component.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-layout-component@4.x.x/dist/aframe-layout-component.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-event-set-component@5.x.x/dist/aframe-event-set-component.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a-scene stats>
            <a-assets>

                <img crossorigin="anonymous" id="node1" src="https://static.thearchmedia.com/media/documents/a-frame_images/node1.jpg">
            </a-assets>
            <a-camera>
              <a-cursor></a-cursor>
            </a-camera>

        <a-sky id="image-360" src="#node1" color="#fff" animation__fade="property: components.material.material.color; type: color; from: #FFF; to: #000; dur: 300; startEvents: fade" animation__fadeback="property: components.material.material.color; type: color; from: #000; to: #FFF; dur: 300; startEvents: animationcomplete__fade"></a-sky>
        <!-- Link template we will build. --> 
        <!-- Camera + Cursor. -->
        </a-scene>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your cursor is not getting stuck. Your experience has very low frame rate. Unlikely that someone has time to profile your whole code base. I recommend stripping down your experience and add elements until you find what makes it slow. You can then share a simple runnable example to reproduce. More likely you’ll get specific actionable advice.

Comment: Thanks! I knew that I was going to have performance issues with the number of assets I'm trying to serve. I still need to optimize.

Comment: So I implemented "stats" on a-scene to measure the performance. After the frame rate reaches 60fps, I switch to "VR". My phone is able to pan through the scene, but the cursor is still stuck. I'm not sure why the cursor would be stuck if the frames are consistently between 50fps and 60fps.

Comment: Your code is pretty complex. I suggest narrowing it down to something simple. It will make it easier for people to look at it.

Comment: Okay I stripped the code the bar minimum and add some screen shots from my phone to show what it happening.

Comment: Provide a link so people can easily run your code https://glitch.com/~aframe

Comment: https://glitch.com/~witty-crowd-9i1tjo6z